# Cannot Access Magento Admin when Site Root not in Domain Root

Tags: magento, admin

I don't think this question is a duplicate.

There are similar questions, but none addressing this particular cause.

Server is CentOS Apache, PHP 5.3.10

I have 2 copies of the same Magento site. The admin works in one, but not the other.

Where it works, the Magento installation is in the site root:

e.g. `www.example.com` leads you to the website, and `www.example.com/admin` brings you to the admin.

But the other copy is in:

`www.example.com/othersite/`

So I try to access the admin via `www.example.com/othersite/admin` but I get a 404 error.

I tried editing app/etc/local.xml so that it reads "othersite/admin" instead of just "admin" but that did not fix the problem. I've restarted apache several times although that should not do anything anyway.

I've seen a solution that involved setting a certain values in the database to '0' in 4 different tables (e.g. in `core_store`). Those values are already 0 so I didn't run any queries.

Thank you

EDIT:

Also note I tried changing the admin access on the working site to `test/admin` instead of just `admin` in `local.xml`. It didn't work. Changing it to just `test` did work. Does Magento not allow admin to be located in a subfolder? Is this a url rewrite problem?

Comment: Have you tried `www.example.com/othersite/index.php/admin`? This sometimes works for me in odd situations like this

Comment: And you've changed `web/unsecure/base_url` and `web/secure/base_url` in the `core_config_data` table? [See Magento Wiki article](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/update_site_url_in_core_config_data)